# NHibernate - AliasToBean and Associations

Tags: nhibernate

I have an entity which looks like this:

```
public class MyEntity {
 public virtual int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual string Name { get; set ; }
 public virtual Role UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

The property "Name" is not a mapped property but "Id" and "UserRole" is. I want to populate this class using a custom criteria like this:

```
ICriteria c = Db.CreateCriteria<MyEntity>("m")
 .CreateAlias("Role", "r")
 .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
 .Add(
  Projections.SqlProjection(@"Name = case TypeId
                    when 2 then (select Name from tblOne where Id = EntityId)
                    when 4 then (select Name from tblTwo where Id = EntityId)
                    when 3 then (select Name from tblThree where Id = EntityId)
                    end", new string[] { "Name" }, new NHibernate.Type.IType[] { NHibernateUtil.String }))
                .Add(Projections.Property("m.Id"), "Id")
                .Add(Projections.Property("r.Id"), "UserRole.Id")
                .Add(Projections.Property("r.Desc"), "UserRole.Desc")
                .Add(Projections.Property("r.Permission"), "UserRole.Permission")
    )
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<EntityPermission>());
```

However if I execute this it throws an exception "Could not find a setter for property '{UserRole.Id}' in class 'MyEntity'".

So my question is doesn't aliastobean support associations, and if it does, what's the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You should crate an alias to "UserRole" instead of "Role", since the name of the property is "UserRole", not "Role".